# mysql high availablity for LAMP application (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: linux, mysql, php, cluster, glusterfs

im trying to achieve HIGH Availability (HA) for a LAMP application(News Portal website) which might be of interest to many unfamiliar users.For files im using Glusterfs (replica) for redundancy between two apache-linux-box's with two HAproxy/keepalived linux box on the front as load balancers but im confused for mysql database server HA.i have 2 separate ubuntu 14.04 to serve as mysqlserver.
i have spent days on researching and decided to give a try on MySQL 5.6.16 with 25.5 wsrep and  Galera wsrep 25.3.5. , I have also read about tungsten, mysql NDB. Can you suggest me any hints/architecture-diagrams/links to improve or achieve HA and good performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a master-master MySQL replication setup.

- Set auto_increment_increment on both servers to 2.
- Set auto_increment_offset on one server to the (default) 1, and to 2 on the other server.

With this scheme both servers can concurrently insert data into auto-increment tables without getting in each other's way, so that both servers can be used to update the database. Of course the software needs to be a bit smart when updating existing records that you can't have both servers updating the same record at the same time; this could be prevented by using `keepalived` or whatever to designate one of the servers as the "write" server until that server becomes unavailable.